# Python 3 - Module taking hours to execute, csv file

Tags: python, performance, csv

I'm a beginner with python but it seemed like a good tool for the task i needed done.

The purpose of the script is to clean/sort and pick out specific datasets from a quite large csv-file (1,6 million rows and 8 columns).

I understand that some of the lines in the code is not very efficient but the script has been running for 20+ hours now. I have recieved no error code in the shell but i suspect that I've crossed some kind of capacity limit.

to be clear, the code is still executing on my laptop, 8 GB RAM and m3-6Y30 processor.

Do I have really slow code or is there some infinite loop somewhere or have i done some fatal error?

It's okay if the code is just slow, I just wonder if should turn it off and begin a new because it's not going to work.

CG063_formatted is the large one, and MasterClean2 is a smaller one already cleaned. They are from the same source. Unfortunately I can't show you the contents of the files.

All help is appreciated.

```
import csv

f1 = open('CG063_formatted.csv', "r")
f2 = open('MasterClean2.csv', "r")
f13 = open('Master_add.csv', "w")


csv_f1 = csv.reader(f1, delimiter=',')
csv_f2 = csv.reader(f2, delimiter=',')
csv_f13 = csv.writer(f13, lineterminator='\n')

Prov_param = ['LSP1_NV_BSFC', 'LSP1_NV_FlwFuel', 'LSP1_NV_PCAC', 'LSP1_NV_Pwr', 'LSP3_NV_BSFC', 'LSP3_NV_FlwFuel', 'LSP3_NV_PCAC', 'LSP3_NV_Pwr', 'LST2_NV_BSFC', 'LST2_NV_FlwFuel', 'LST2_NV_TrqEng']

Prov_param2 = ['6', '7', '8', '9', '11']


# ------ Clean / remove duplicate ------- #

DataList = []
for line in csv_f1:
    if line in DataList or line[2] != '1':
        continue
    else:
        DataList.append( line )


DataList2 = []
for line in DataList:
    for row in csv_f2:
        if line[1] == row[0]:
            continue
        else:
            DataList2.append(line)

# ------ Main ------ #

DataList3 = []
for line in Datalist2:
    for row in DataList3:
        if line[1] == row[0]:
            continue
        else:
            DataList3.append(list(range(56)))   #create list with range 56 in DataList3
            row[0] = line[1]                    #place LOPNUMMER in column 1 DataList3

for row in DataList3:                           #place 0 in all cells except column 1
    for item in row:
        if item != NULL:
            item = '0'

for line in DataList2:
    for row in DataList3:
        if line[1] == row[0]:                    #LOPNUMMER@Datalist2 == LOPNUMMER@Datalist3 ?
            k=1
            for item in Prov_param2:            #test type? 6,7,8,9,11?
                k= k+11
                if item == line[5]:
                    break
            i=0
            for item2 in Prov_param:             #Which test parameter?
                i=i+1
                if item == line[4]:
                    break
            row[i+k] = line[6]                  # write the test value to cell in DataList3



# ------ print to file -------- #

for row in csv_f2:
    csv_f13.writerow(row)

for row in DataList3:
    csv_f13.writerow(row)


# ------ Close / return value ------ #

f1.close()
f2.close()
f13.close()
```

Comment: You'd better run your code one-line-at-a-time in your Python console and then you can track which line is the problem. When you figure out which part is the problem, it'll be easier for everyone to examine it.

Comment: It's likely the `if line in DataList`. Element lookup in lists is very slow if the list grows big. Consider using a set instead.

Comment: Also, your nested `for` loops with `Datalist.append(...)` inside are probably causing the size of your lists to explode. I'm 99% certain this code doesn't do what you intended to do.

Comment: I don't think your code is doing what you want it to do, for a really simple reason.  At one point, you're doing a comparison with something called `NULL`.  If Python was reaching that point, you would be seeing an error because `NULL` doesn't mean anything in Python and you haven't defined it anywhere in your script.  This won't help fix your issue, but for future reference you should use `None` instead of `NULL`, and use the `is` comparison operator instead of `==` when trying to compare with `None`.

Comment: You could try to do everything in one loop, without creating huge lists in the process. For example, get an element from the first file, then another element from the second file and do the operations you need on them. 

You could also "clean" the first file first and this will reduce the size of the file you want to process.

Comment: There are several problems with your code. One important flaw is `for line in DataList: for row in csv_f2:` The inner loop will only run once; on subsequent iterations of the outer loop there are no rows left to read. You can fix that by rewinding the file pointer with `f2.seek(0)`.

Comment: As Rawing said, `if line in DataList or line[2] != '1':` will be slow because it has to perform a linear search through `DataList` for every line you test. It would be _much_ faster to have a set of lines (or perhaps line hashes) to do the deduping (assuming you have enough RAM). Alternatively, remove dupes before passing the data to your Python code, eg using the `uniq` shell command (or its equivalent in your OS).

Comment: Also, it's more efficient to do the fast test before the slow test, eg `if line[2] != '1' or line in DataSet:`; the 2nd test won't be performed if the 1st test is True.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments! I'm gonna try and redo and test on a smaller scale. I have done some c programming earlier and thats probably where my annoying use of operators come from! Thanks!